# How to get the maximum column width using TableColumnAdjuster on a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The [`TableColumnAdjuster`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) is a great tool, but I just can't seem to get the table to show the full width of each of the columns. I can't see the whole header, which can sometimes be quite long.

Here is what I have:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
    tca.adjustColumns();
    tca.setColumnHeaderIncluded(true);
    tca.setColumnDataIncluded(true);
    tca.setOnlyAdjustLarger( true );
    tca.setDynamicAdjustment( false );
```

but the column header is partially hidden unless I manually resize. Any ideas about how to show the full width of the column so I can see the whole header?

Comment: Same advice as your last question. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Again the SSCCE will be a JFrame, a JTable added to a JScrollPane. Hardcoded data in the TableModel. So the total code will be about 20 lines of code.

Comment: Is a SSCCE always necessary? Especially when the answer is likely to be simple as per this question

Comment: `Is a SSCCE always necessary?` Yes! Until the problem is solved you don't know what is or isn't relevant.  You don't know how simple the solution may be. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setDynamicAdjustment(true); //false will work for the static data
you might wann change it to `true`.
```

call `adjustColumns()` at the very end after setting the properties.

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of the TableColumnAdjuster is to include both the header and the data when determining the column width. There is no need to change any property.

Here is a simple SSCCE that takes 5 minutes to create and easily demonstrates this default of the TableColumnAdjuster:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        String[] columnNames = {"Column1", "Column with big header text", "Column3"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 3);
        model.setValueAt("column1 data", 0, 0);
        model.setValueAt("column2 data", 1, 1);
        model.setValueAt("column3 long data", 2, 2);

        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        add( new JScrollPane( table ) );

        //  use default behaviour

        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        TableColumnAdjuster tca = new TableColumnAdjuster(table);
        tca.adjustColumns();
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

This code works properly, so the question is why doesn't it work for you?

What are you doing differently? Is your usage causing a bug in the code?

Is the solution you accepted the proper solution or is there a better solution?

Is the problem a OS version/platform issue?

Unless we can see your SSCCE we can't answer any of these questions.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Turns out I just had to change setDynamicAdjustment to true and put adjustColumns at the end but the SSCCE issue is taken on board

Comment: @SebastianZeki, You completely missed the point of my answer. I did NOT need to change any of the code you posted and it still works as expected for me. So why is your usage of the class causing a problem??? So the problem has NOT been solved. A workaround has been used. Did you even test this code? Does it work as expected?

Comment: I understood the point. As per the question I couldn't display the full header of my JTable by default. Using suggestion from @Priyamal now I can. So the problem is solved

Comment: @SebastianZeki, No you don't understand the point. What happens when you execute the code I just posted? Is the full header displayed or not?  It is a simple question?

Comment: @SebastianZeki, `I couldn't display the full header of my JTable by default.` - Are you talking about your original code or the code I just posted??? If you are talking about the code I just posted then we have a OS version/platform issue. How do you expect me to improve the class is you don't provide feedback?

Comment: OK so yes that code works fine so I am still at a loss as to why my code doesn't show. But the thing is (yes I know its lazy) the workaround works so I kind of feel OK about not pursuing this...Apologies