# Is it possible jtable row in optionDialog box

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable.

Some of the cells contain very long strings and trying to scroll left and right through it is difficult. My question is whether it is possible to show a row from a JTable in a pop-up eg showDialog type box (ie where the selected row is organised as a column).

Even a link to a tutorial would do.

I have scoured the internet but I don't think I'm really using the correct keywords as I get a lot of right-click options.

If this is not possible are there any other suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: `where the selected row is organised as a column` - not sure what that means but yes it is possible. However, you still haven't replied to my question for you when I answered one of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37606317/131872.

Comment: Wow. That's impressive persistence. I added an answer now to that other unrelated question but the workaround worked so being lazy (I know people like me should be...) I haven't pursued it (in the end its only me who will suffer I know....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513), the [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) factory methods will display the `Object` passed in the `message` parameter. If that `message` is a one column `JTable`, you can recycle any custom [renderers and editors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) that were applied to the original table.

In outline,

- Add a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to your table and get the `selectedRow`.
- Iterate through the table's model and construct a `newModel` whose rows are the columns of the `selectedRow`.
- Create a `JTable newTable = new JTable(newModel)`.
- Apply any non-default renderers and editors.
- Pass a `new JScrollPane(newTable)` as the `message` parameter to your chosen `JOptionPane` method.

Starting from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37318673/230513), the following listener displays the dialog pictured.

[image]

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int selectedRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
        if (selectedRow > -1) {
            DefaultTableModel newModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            String rowName = "Row: " + selectedRow;
            newModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{rowName});
            for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                newModel.addRow(new Object[]{model.getValueAt(selectedRow, i)});
            }
            JTable newTable = new JTable(newModel) {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                    return new Dimension(140, 240);
                }
            };
            // Apply any custom renderers and editors
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, new JScrollPane(newTable),
                rowName, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oops, almost forgot to [translate cell coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25317943/230513).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following `ListSelectionListener`:

```
final JTable dialogTable =new JTable();     
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
            if (selectedRow > -1) {
                int columnCount = table.getModel().getColumnCount();
                Object[] column = new Object[]{"Row "+(selectedRow+1)};
                Object[][] data = new Object[columnCount][1];
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                    Object obj = table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, i);
                    data[i][0] = obj;
                }
                dialogTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(data, column));                  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(dialogTable));
            }
        }
});
```

This is going to show a message dialog which contains a `JTable` with data that is derived from the selected row. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I want to show all the values in the row, each in their cel, organised vertically- that's what I meant by 'in a column'. I think this code will show me just an individual cell value

Comment: Why not a `ListSelectionListener` instead of a `MouseListener`?

Comment: @SebastianZeki Could you please take a look at my answer. I have edited it to suit your needs.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha: Good catch on empty selection, but don't forget to [translate cell coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25317943/230513).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to show all the values in the row, each in their cel, organised vertically- that's what I meant by 'in a column'.

That should be in the question, not in the comment.

There is no default functionality for this but you can do it yourself.

You could create a JPanel (maybe using a GridBagLayout), with two labels in a row to represent the data in a column of the selected row of the table.

For the data in the first label you would use the `getColumnName(...)` method of the TableModel.

For the data in the second label you would use the `getValueAt(...)` method of the TableModel.

Another option is to simply display a tool tip for the cell. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Specifying ToolTips For Cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip) for more information.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I've gone with @trashgod's answer but this is also very helpful