# How to word wrap inside a JTable row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple JTable that shows the details (in column format) of a row from another JTable. This works nicely. However, sometimes the text in a row is very long so the user ends up having to scroll across which isnt neat.

How can I wrap the text in a row and allow the row height to change to show all the text in it.

Here is the code:

```
 table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    int selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
                    DefaultTableModel newModel = new DefaultTableModel();
                    String rowName = "Row: " + selectedRow;
                    newModel.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{rowName});
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        newModel.addRow(new Object[]{table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRow, i)});
                    }
                    JTable newTable = new JTable(newModel) {
                        /**
                         * 
                         */
                        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                        @Override
                        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                            return new Dimension(140, 240);
                        }
                    };
                    newTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                    newTable.setRowHeight(14, 30);
                    TableColumnAdjuster tcanewTable = new TableColumnAdjuster(newTable);        
                    tcanewTable.setColumnHeaderIncluded(true);
                    tcanewTable.setColumnDataIncluded(true);
                    tcanewTable.setOnlyAdjustLarger( true );
                    tcanewTable.setDynamicAdjustment( true );
                    tcanewTable.adjustColumns();

                    // Apply any custom renderers and editors
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, new JScrollPane(newTable),
                        rowName, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem. You have been asked in the past to post a `SSCCE` with every question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37606317/131872

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a `JTextArea` as a `TableCellRenderer` for that column in your table.  For example:

```
static class WordWrapCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    WordWrapCellRenderer() {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText(value.toString());
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(), getPreferredSize().height);
        if (table.getRowHeight(row) != getPreferredSize().height) {
            table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

To use `WordWrapCellRenderer` in your table:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(new WordWrapCellRenderer());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an update of the accepted answer.

It makes the renderer more efficient by limiting the number of `getPreferredSize()` calls.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/**
 *  The WordWrapRenderer can be used as a renderer for a JTable column. It will
 *  allow the text to wrap to a new line and adjust the table row height.
 *
 *  Note. This renderer can only be used for a single column in the table.
 */
public class WordWrapRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer
{
    WordWrapRenderer()
    {
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        setText( (value == null) ? "" : value.toString() );
        setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(), table.getRowHeight(row));

        //  Recalculate the preferred height now that the text and renderer width have been set.

        int preferredHeight = getPreferredSize().height;

        if (table.getRowHeight(row) != preferredHeight)
        {
            table.setRowHeight(row, preferredHeight);
        }

        return this;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JTable table = new JTable(2, 3);
        table.setValueAt("A", 0, 0);
        table.setValueAt("This text should wrap by default", 0, 1);

        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer( new WordWrapRenderer() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableBasic");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```